# ElasticSearch query filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

My intent is to fetch records matching a specified date range and uuid (Unique User ID). The query seems to fail:
[image: screenshot of UUID based search query and result]

If I try the same query with username then it works.

[image: screenshot of Name based search query and result]

I suspected the `:` character in the search string and tried escaping it with a `\` but it still didn't work.

What could be the problem ?

The mappings are:

```
{
  "top_flows": {
    "mappings": {
      "top flows": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "postDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "uuid": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON document being added into elasticsearch is:

```
doc = {
                        'postDate': timestamp_str,
                        'uuid': uuid,
                        'name': 'sam'
}
timestamp = time.time()
timestamp_str = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
res = self.__eshandle.index(index="top_flows", doc_type='top flows', id=int(timestamp), body=doc)
```

Comment: To make it easier to help, please add the code for the query as text.

Comment: Can you show your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem is that you did not turned of analysis on term field in [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).

Put mapping

```
PUT /top_flows
{
  "mappings": {
    "users": { 
      "properties": { 
        "uuid":  {
          "type":   "string", 
          "index":  "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Save document

```
POST /top_flows/blogpost
{
"uuid": "FF:FF:FF:FF"
}
```

Search

```
POST /top_flows/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }  ,
  "post_filter": {
"term": {
      "uuid": "FF:FF:FF:FF"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the new mappings show above but still did not return any results. Edited the question to show the mappings, JSON doc and ES indexing im using for reference.

Comment: They are not the same in your mappings you have missing index not analyzed

Comment: hi Volodymyr, I tried using the example you gave here but even that didn't work for me. Not sure, where i'm going wrong exactly. Can you try using the JSON doc I've provided and see if it works for u? Maybe the indexing I'm trying is wrong? All I want to do is insert the docs indexed by timestamp and then search them based on time range and uuid or user. I'm very new to elasticsearch so excuse me if I'm asking naive questions :)

Comment: @Athif I have posted you example which i tried. And which works. In addition, you mapping is wrong. Delete index and try to run all my commands

Comment: Hey Volodymyr, your example worked ! The first time I tried the old index I think didn't get DELETE'ed properly. After deleting it when I tried your example, it worked perfectly. Thanks alot

Comment: @Athif It must because i checked before posting, Dont forget to mark as resolved and +1 :)

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr. I did check but didn't double-check ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below worked out finally !

```
GET /top_flows/_search
{
    "query" : {
              "range" : {
                  "postDate" : {
                    "from" : "now-5m",
                    "to" : "now"
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": { 
      "query_string": {
        "query": "FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF\\:11\\:8F\\:FF\\:FF\\:FF",
        "fields": ["uuid"]
      }
    }
}
```

Not sure still why the earlier approaches failed :(